# Java check GET request info

Tags: java, spring, facebook, spring-restcontroller, ngrok

I'm working with Facebook messenger app (chatbot) and I want to see what GET request I'm receiving from it. I'm using Spring Framework to start http server and ngrok to make it visible for facebook.

Facebook sending webhooks to me and i receive them, but i don't understand how to extract data from this request. Here what i get when I try *HttpRequest* to receive GET request. [ngrok screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0UVJ.png) (error 500).
When I tried without `HttpRequest`, i had response 200 (ok).

What do i need to put to parameters of my ***find*** method to see GET request data?

My code:

```
@RestController
public class botAnswer {

    @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String find(HttpRequest request) {
        System.out.println(request.getURI());
        String aaa = "222";

        return aaa;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `HttpRequest` will not help you here. For simplicity, just change `HttpRequest` to `HttpServletRequest`. You can access all query string parameters from it using `request.getParameter("...")`. Something like the following should work:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String handleMyGetRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    // Reading the value of one specific parameter ...
    String value = request.getParameter("myParam");

    // or all parameters 
    Map<String, String[]> params = request.getParameterMap();

    ...
}
```

[This blog post](https://www.journaldev.com/3358/spring-requestmapping-requestparam-pathvariable-example) shows how to use the `@RequestParam` annotation as an alternative to reading the parameters from `HttpServletRequest` directly.